# Why speedtest.net know my IP address even though I had used a proxy?

Tags: proxy, ip, ip-address, privacy, squid

I am using my own squid proxy server,when I check my ip address on whatismyip.com, it show the ip address of my proxy server.

But, when I check on speedtest.net, I found that they can track my client IP.

Is there any ways to prevent my real IP being detected ???

Comment: Are you using a local proxy, or remote proxy? speedtest will only know the IP that's making the connection.

Comment: it is a remote proxy

Answer (score -1):

Your IP is provided by your ISP (internet service provider) and speedtest.net picks up your gateway/router.

Thus "trying" to hide behind a proxy would not have any effect.